# c# client application getting exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml-rpc

I am new to c# and programming, developing API client to communicate to odoo API over xml-rpc, getting exception in console as

*fault response contains string value where integer expected [fault response : struct mapped to type Fault : member faultCode mapped to type Int32]*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [XmlRpcUrl("")]
public interface odoologin : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("login")]
        int login(string dbName, string dbUser, string dbPwd);
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            odoologin rpcClientlogin;
            String host = "http://127.0.0.1:8069";
            String UserName = "admin";
            String pwd = "pdm@alligator";
            String dbName = "demo";

            rpcClientlogin = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<odoologin>();
            rpcClientlogin.Url= host + "/xmlrpc/object";
            try
            {
                var userid = rpcClientlogin.login(dbName, UserName, pwd);
                Console.WriteLine(userid);
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change `int login(string dbName, string dbUser, string dbPwd);` with `string login(string dbName, string dbUser, string dbPwd);`

Comment: tried the same , did not work though.